# MVC access Viewbag value from parent view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have view " child.cshtml " that inherited from " _Parent.cshtml " , on _Parent.cshtml i have :

```
ViewBag.Title = "some value";
```

on child.cshtml i have :

```
@{
    Layout = "_Parent.cshtml";
}
<h1>Here i want to put layout title</h1>
```

How can i access ViewBag.Title value in child.cshtml view from Parent.cshtml ?

Comment: You can use `javascript` for that.

Comment: @Akshay: Not as written. The ViewBag is only visible server-side.

Comment: You need to show more of both your views as this question is not very clear at the moment. The last sentence makes no sense at all. It is unusual to inherit views, as you already have `_ViewStart.cshtml` and layouts, so a clear example of what you are doing is needed :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - you can access your `ViewBag` value in `razor` in `cshtml`. Store that in a `string` and use it in `javascript`.

Comment: @Akshay: Sure, but that is not what they appear to be asking. They appear to want to cross-reference ViewBag values in inherited views. This would appear to have nothing to do with client-side processing.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie -  In parent `cshtml` page, you can store the value in `localStorage`. So it will be accessible through out.

Comment: @Akshay: That is just getting silly. This appears to be a completely server-side problem. local-storage is a client-side only technology.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - You are just not getting it.

Comment: @Akshay: *One of us* certainly does not get it. I will wait for more details before suggesting a solution myself. Feel free to post your guesses as an answer for others to review :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i updated my question but there are no more details, its very simple, How can i access ViewBag.Title on parent view ?

Comment: @AhmadAlaa: communication of the `ViewBag.Title` typically goes the other direction.  It's set in the View, and then rendered in the Layout.  Why are you trying to reverse this?

Comment: Your grammar on the last sentence appears to be backwards, compared to your new comment. The question becomes: *what do you wish to do with the ViewBag.Title value?* Use it for the browser page title? That is usually done in the master-page/layout file. It is not clear why you are inheriting a page at all yet.

Comment: @SamAxe because i want to put page title in some html tags in child view, but the main question is, can i access any property on parent view from child view ? instead of using javascript

Comment: 'Fraid not.  View's get processed first, then Layouts.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Perhaps they used the wrong word.  This appears to be a standard View/Layout scenario.  I do not see anything to indicate inheritance, except for the OP's use of that word.

Comment: This question appears to be trying to use the `title` backwards. The title normally varies *per child page/view* and the layout simply displays that information. Having a single title, the same in all pages is pointless.